# How to include percent calculations in pivot statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Using a pivot statement, I am able to break down the count in a table of data by title:

```
select * from (
  select * from ta
)
pivot (
COUNT(title)
 for title in ( 'worker', 'manager') )
```

So the result looks like this:

```
STATUS    'worker'  'manager'
started   3         1
finished  4         5
ready     3         4
```

What I need to add to it is the percentages, i.e.

```
STATUS    'worker'  percent  'manager'   percent
started   3         30%      1           10%
finished  4         40%      5           50%
ready     3         30%      4           40%
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this within the same statement?
see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6c04a/1/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using conditional aggregation, You may use -

```
select STATUS
      ,WORKER
      ,WORKER/SUM(WORKER) OVER()*100 percent
      ,MANAGER
      ,MANAGER/SUM(MANAGER) OVER()*100 percent 
from (
  select * from ta
)
pivot (
COUNT(title)
 for title in ( 'worker' AS WORKER, 'manager' AS MANAGER))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=63f4cee4f82fa5c40ed41625a277d1e2) is the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation and window functions:

```
select status,
       sum(case when title = 'worker' then 1 else 0 end) as worker,
       sum(case when title = 'manager' then 1 else 0 end) as manager,
       (sum(case when title = 'worker' then 1 else 0 end) /
        sum(sum(case when title = 'worker' then 1 else 0 end)) over ()
       ) as worker,
       (sum(case when title = 'manager' then 1 else 0 end) /
        sum(sum(case when title = 'manager' then 1 else 0 end)) over ()
       ) as manager
from ta
group by status;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6c04a/3) is a sql<>fiddle.